# What happens when acetone reacts with hydrogen cyanide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

> Which of the following is the major organic product when acetone is allowed to react with hydrogen cyanide in the presence of a catalytic amount of sodium cyanide?
>
> [image]

The correct answer is (B).

However, I got this answer without using the catalytic sodium cyanide.  In my proposed mechanism, the dissociated proton from $\ce{HCN}$ activates the carbonyl, which facilitates the nucleophilic attack of $\ce{CN-}$.

What role does the $\ce{NaCN}$ play?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The acetone carbonyl is attacked by the CN$^-$ that comes from the NaCN.  This tetrahedral intermediate has a oxygen anion, which then grabs a proton from the HCN, regenerating the CN$^-$.

Answer (score 2):

The product that is formed is [cyanohydrin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanohydrin).

> Cyanohydrins can be formed by the cyanohydrin reaction, which involves
>   treating a ketone or an aldehyde with hydrogen cyanide ($\ce{HCN}$) in the
>   presence of excess amounts of sodium cyanide ($\ce{NaCN}$) as a catalyst:
>
> $$\ce{RR’C=O + HCN → RR’C(OH)CN}$$

Since, the reactant is acetone both R and R' are $\ce{CH3 -}$ group.

> In this reaction, the nucleophilic $\ce{CN^−}$ ion attacks
>   the electrophilic carbonyl carbon in the ketone, followed by
>   protonation by $\ce{HCN}$, thereby regenerating the cyanide anion.

---

Now, what is the function of catalyst sodium cyanide?

> For successful cyanohydrin formation it is important to have free
>   cyanide ions available to react with the ketone or aldehyde. This can
>   be achieved by using a salt (e.g. $\ce{KCN}$ or $\ce{NaCN}$) or a silylated
>   (e.g. $\ce{Me3SiCN}$) form of cyanide under acidic conditions or by using $\ce{HCN}$
>   with some base added to produce the needed $\ce{CN^−}$ nucleophile.([Here](https://chem.libretexts.org/LibreTexts/Athabasca_University/Chemistry_360%3A_Organic_Chemistry_II/Chapter_19%3A_Aldehydes_and_Ketones%3A_Nucleophilic_Addition_Reactions/19.06_Nucleophilic_Addition_of_HCN%3A_Cyanohydrin_Formation))